# Sample configuration to speed up POVRAY image creation

Tags: performance, image-processing, povray

We're using POV-Ray to generate some 80 images per run, which we stitch together to form two  moving GIF files (two 360 degree views of a scene). We're looking for ways to speed-up this image creation (on a headless linux server) as much as possible, as they'll be displayed on a webpage directly following creation.

Now I know setup might be suboptimal, as POV-Ray is mostly designed for high quality images, but unfortunately this process can't be altered as it's an external tool that generates the POV-Ray files.

Given that we're stitching multiple images together into a moving GIF, I suspect there's a lot of performance to be gained in lowering the image quality, colors, lighting and such, but unfortunately I have no prior experience with POV-Ray or any of these settings.

I was wondering if anyone would be able to provide or guide me to a sample configuration that will speed-up this image creation as much as possible, without a much noticeable loss in image quality.

Best regards,
Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colour depth will not make a huge difference. Like most ray tracing programs, the greatest performance improvements are through reducing the rays being traced. You can do this by lowering the size of the picture (resolution) and by decreasing (or removing) anti-aliasing (-A) and lowering quality (+Q0). These will get you your 80% of the 80-20 rule.

Comment: Thanks! Turning Antialias off and setting Quality to 2 already brought the run time down from 384 to 286 seconds. The image size was already set to 400 x 300...
Anything else I could try to bring it down even further?

Comment: Setting Bits_Per_Color to 4 does seem to speed things up somewhat, but no hard numbers to verify this.. Might be good to know for any future readers.

Answer (score 3):

The manner in which your object is created can greatly affect render time (# of blob components, # of triangles, # of pixels in height field; isosurface vs. other).

Light is a key player: reduce the number of lights and use of radiosity.  Sometimes one can do tricks with texturing (such as a slope pigment pattern) that can simulate lighting.  Light groups also help.